# Push constant block values are weirdly offseted

Tags: layout, glsl, vulkan

I have this push constant block:

```c
layout(push_constant) uniform PC {
    vec4 value1;
    vec4 value2;
    uint values[2];
    uint value3;
    uint value4;
} pc;
```

And a corresponding struct in C:

```c
struct {
    float value1[4];
    float value2[4];
    uint32_t values[2];
    uint32_t padding1__[2];
    uint32_t value3;
    uint32_t value4;
};
```

Note that the padding was inserted to respect std140 (arrays of scalar values should be padded to the nearest alignment of vec4).

But upon debugging it seems that `value3` and `value4` take the value of `padding1__[0]` and `padding1__[1]` respectively instead of the desired values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 4.4.5 of the OpenGL Shading Language specification says:

> The initial state of compilation when generating SPIR-V is as if the following were declared:
>
> ```
>     layout(std140, column_major) uniform;
>     layout(std430, column_major) buffer;
> ```
>
> However, when push_constant is declared, the default layout of the buffer will be std430. There is
> no method to globally set this default.

So the block doesn't use the std140 layout, but instead it uses std430, as such removing the padding fixes the problem